# Получить скриншот видео vk

Tags: screenshots, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Как получить скриншот видео в vk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы о тех превьюшках, которые создаются самим VK, то про них есть [в документации](https://vk.com/dev/methods):

1. Поля `photo_*` метода [video.get](https://vk.com/dev/video.get)
2. Поля `thumb`, `image_*` метода [video.getUserVideos](https://vk.com/dev/video.getUserVideos)

Comment: чего то у меня не выполняется video.get  ошибку возвращает

Answer (score 4):

Клавишей Prt Scr на клаве и правой кнопкой мыши "вставить" в Paint, например. Ещё в win7 есть инструмент "Ножницы".

Вы смотрели в [документации платформы](https://vk.com/dev/main)?

Comment: я надеюсь это шутка.... про Prt Scr  я про api vk, как получить скриншот видео по ссылке на php

Comment: @ukroficer скорее сарказм, почитайте [доки][1], там это есть. Обратите внимание на photo_130, photo_320 в ответе.


  [1]: https://vk.com/dev/video.get